# Function "say" throws up an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm setting up a new discord bot using the `@bot.command()` functionality, however, my `!say` command will not take the user's input and then have the bot say it

```
@bot.command()
async def say(message):
  #await bot.delete_message(message)
  await bot.send_message(message.channel, message)
```

This is for a discord server and the bot is to auto admin things for me aswell as provide the discord members functions to use. I've tried:

- bot.say(message)
- bot.say(message.channel, message)
- bot.send_message(messsage)
- bot.send_message(message.channel, messsage)

The expected result is for the bot to "say" the user's message e.g. with `!say Hello` the bot would reply with "Hello"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `channel.send()` for example:

```
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

You can see more explained Examples at: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: @Mooles if that solved your problem, could you please accept this answer by clicking the tick on the left? This will mark your question as resolved ;)

Comment: Ah sorry still new to Stack Overflow